# Grayscale filter on text, removes part of the text on Ghost's Casper

Tags: css, antialiasing, grayscale, ghost

I've been searching the web for quite a while and couldn't find an answer.

First, let me explain what I'm trying to achieve, some websites are using grayscale antialiasing on their texts and it makes them look better. (IMO)

Here's an example from medium: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8fXI.png
If you zoom in, the text remains gray.

Twitter does it too: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgNq2.png

Now, an example that doesn't do it, Google: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijuC4.png
I've modified CSS and applied `filter: grayscale(0%);` which is the only way that I know to achieve this effect.

Modified Google: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5B4b6.png

---

Now, my problem. Ghost doesn't do this by default: https://demo.ghost.io/welcome/

You can see it here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDOpQ.png

When I apply the thing I did to Google above, this happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4Ctu.png

The numbers are gone, half eaten.

Here's a better picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2UJr.png

---

All I did is adding `filter: grayscale(0%);` on both Google and here. It works brilliantly on Google. Also worked in Wordpress but in Ghost, I have this weird problem.

Is there any way to fix this OR how Twitter, Medium etc. are doing this? I tried to look at their CSS but there's nothing about grayscaling or filters. Also saw some anti-aliasing stuff that's supposed to do this but on Chrome nothing does it.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with their CSS and have come to conclusion: The ordered (and numbered) list `ol` that you describe seems to interfere with filters and doesn't accept them like that. But that's a structual problem. It would definitely help if we (or them) change the markup-structure or search for CSS attributes that make this problem happen.

The following worked for me:

```
body { filter: grayscale(0%) };
```

Alternatively, you can easily apply the `filter` to `p` or `div` elements, which contains your desired text.

Comment: Haha, who would've guessed, it was that simple.

`body { filter: grayscale(0%) };` did the job for me. Applying it like `p
    {
       /* filter: grayscale(0%); */
    }` however, doesn't work and still breaks it. However, you solved my problem. Thank you. I've awarded the promised bounty and selected your answer as the answer. Since it does the job.

Edit: Stackoverflow says I can award bounty 2 hours later. See you again in 2 hours I guess.

Comment: Alright, glad I could help. :) I will inform you when I find another solution to why it still breaks the numbers.

Comment: I'd be glad, because it really doesn't make any sense for me.